# Is there a python function that can generate multiple sums so I can avoid multiple individual lines of code?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working in Python with a dataframe by_year, which has columns payee, payment_date and amount. To calculate the sum of the amount totals for each month of the year, I ran the following line of code 12 times for each month

```
by_year[by_year.payment_date.str.contains("January")].amount.sum()
```

Wondering if there's a more efficient way to write a block of code that would generate the amounts for every month

Edit: Here's an excerpt of the data:

```
payee,payment_date,amount
North Park Organization of Business,"December 31, 2019",6534.47
San Diego Housing Commission,"December 31, 2019",44981.33
U S Peroxide LLC,"December 31, 2019",14525.55
Barrett Engineered Pumps Inc,"December 31, 2019",507.39
Aardema Family Ltd Partnership,"December 31, 2019",31750
Gaslamp Quarter Association,"December 31, 2019",5617.3
Hach Company,"December 31, 2019",1860.76
```

Comment: How are the values in the `payment_date` column formatted? Some sample data would be useful.

Comment: Thanks, just added an excerpt of the data

Comment: In which case the solution provided should work as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your date column can be coerced to a pandas timestamp:

```
by_year['payment_date'] = pd.to_datetime(by_year['payment_date'])
year = 2020
df = by_year[by_year['payment_date'].dt.year == year]
df.groupby([df['payment_date'].dt.month]).sum()
```

First convert the dates and then subset the data for your target year.  Finally, use the `dt` accessor method to get the month and group on that, then sum.